# Keeping track of current directory per user

Tags: ruby

I am currently creating a client/server application which is trying to keep track of multiple connected users current directories by way of pairing their unique identifier (username), and a new Dir object to an array of hashes like so:

```
users = []
user = {:user => "userN", :dir => Dir.new(".")}
users.push(user)
...
```

Although when accessing the dir key within the users hash, I can't seem to use the objects methods properly.

For example:

```
users[0][:dir].chdir("../")
```

Returns `undefined method`chrdir`for #<Dir:.>`

Likewise the method `entries` which is supposed to accept 1 argument for listing the contents of a directory, only accepts 0 arguments, and when called with 0 arguments it only lists the current directory initialized when Dir was created.

Is there a simple way to keep track of a user's pseudo location within the filesystem?

Edit:: I found the `Pathname` class and it sort of implements what I need. I am just wondering now if there is a cleaner way to implementing the `cd` and `ls` commands when using it.

```
#Simulate a single users default directory starting point
$dir = Pathname.pwd

#Create a backup of the current directory, change to new directory, 
#test to see if the directory exists and if not return to the backup
def cd(dir)
        backup = $dir
        $dir += dir
        $dir = backup if !($dir.directory?)
end

#Take the array of Pathname objects from entries and convert them 
#to their string directory values and return the sorted array
def ls(dir)
        $dir.entries.map { |pathobject| pathobject.to_s }.sort
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question as I've found out is to use the Pathname class: [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-entries)

It allows you to use the `+=` operator to transverse the file system, although you will have to manually implement many checks to make sure where you are going to transverse to actually exists.

When I implemented my `ls` command I simply mapped the output of Pathname.entries, and sorted the results.

```
def ls(pathname)
    pathname.entries.map { |pathobject| pathobject.to_s }.sort
end
```

This gave you an array of sorted strings of all the files in the current directory that Pathname is set to.

For `cd` you need to make sure the directory exists and if not revert to the previously good directory.

```
def cd(pathname, directory_to_move_to)
    directory_backup = pathname
    pathname += directory_to_move_to
    pathname = directory_backup if !(pathname.directory?)
end
```

Example usage:

```
my_pathname = Pathname.pwd
cd(my_pathname, "../")
ls(my_pathname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem actually isn't using a hash incorrectly, it's that [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) is a global method that changes the working directory of the current process.  [`Dir.entries`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries) is similar.

If you're trying to keep track of a path on a per user basis, you could store it as a [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html), which can also be a directory. That is, directories are represented as a `File`, so even though it's called "file", it can still store a directory path.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to create a File starting at a default directory, then implement such functions such as "cd" to change the Files directory, and "ls" to list all files/directories at the Files location?